# Box-sizing reset in angular material

Tags: angular-material

I'm working on an angular app with material. I'd like to reset the box-sizing globally to avoid future head-ache, and consider 2 options:

Option 1:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Option 2:

```
html {
box-sizing: border-box; 
}
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
```

I like Option 1 because it is clear (everything will be border-box).

Option 2 is more prudent, and takes into consideration angular material's box-sizing.

My question is: Is Option 2 necessary? Will some angular material component malfunctions if they are "forced" to be border-boxed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've looked through the Material css files. The following elements are explicitly "content-box":

- textarea.cdk-textarea-autosize-measuring > impact text-area that have
  the "auto-resize" function
- textarea.cdk-textarea-autosize-measuring-firefox > similarly
- mat-form-field-label-wrapper > impacts some inputs. Removing it
  creates an overflow on placeholders.
- mat-input-element impacts some inputs
- mat-expansion-panel

In my project, mat-expansion-panel has children which inherited content-box(which I did not like). The others were stand-alone inline which could remain content-box for all I cared.

So here is my final reset file, should anyone be interested:

```
body,
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  & .mat-expansion-panel {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```